# Extract and return distinct alphabetic values with MySQL

Tags: mysql, distinct, text-extraction

### Intro

I am creating an AutoComplete street name app. Let's say below are column entries (street names) which only differ by the street number.

- Ahnewinkelstr. 1
- Ahnewinkelstr. 32**B**
- Ahnewinkelstr. 36
- Ahnewinkelstr. 37
- Ahnewinkelstr. 39
- Hansstr. 3
- Hansstr. 6
- Hansstr. 128

Now I would like MySQL to **extract only first alphabetical part** of the street name and **leave out anything after the first numerical char**  and return a list of distinct street names that were extracted.

### RESULT should look like

- Ahnewinkelstr.
- Hansstr.

Do you think this is doable? Before I tried with Hibernate Search to realize this, but that was certainly too complicated.

Comment: What version MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Frankerz I'm intrigued- what possible difference could *that* make?

Comment: @Strawberry See my answer below

Comment: @frankerz oh cool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MariaDB, you have access to [`REGEX_REPLACE()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/regexp_replace/). You could write a query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_REPLACE(`street`, '\\s+\\d.*$', '')
FROM `streets`
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: hi FrankerZ, I do have MariaDB 10.0.32 But I am not getting the desired result. The numerical value (street number) is still inside the ResultSet.

Comment: @Chiggiddi Give me a few minutes. sqlfiddle didn't have a MariaDB, so I'm downloading a version to play around and test

Comment: Thanks so much for your efforts. I remember you helped me in the past. Would be cool to be able to donate to you somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Without a regex replace (as has already been show), you'd probably need to do something ugly, and probably slow, like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(theField, 0
    , LEAST(
          INSTR(theField, '0')
        , INSTR(theField, '1')
        , INSTR(theField, '2')
        , INSTR(theField, '3')
        , INSTR(theField, '4')
        , INSTR(theField, '5')
        , INSTR(theField, '6')
        , INSTR(theField, '7')
        , INSTR(theField, '8')
        , INSTR(theField, '9')
    ) AS beforeNums
FROM ....
```

Comment: Interesting solution. This would work on older versions of MySQL as well. +1

Comment: that sounds really interesting. Fortunately I can make use of the new functions starting with MariaDB 10.0.5. But your answer definetly is a great option for older versions. I will upvote it.

Comment: Yeah, that is why I figured I would add it; I haven't worked with MySQL on a daily basis in a couple years, but the versions I did work with (and still do occasionally) are older ones without such features.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the option you need is `substring_index`. The idea with this is it will return portions of a string based on exploding at certain values. In your case you would run:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Field,'.',1))
FROM your_table
```

See [Substring_index ref from Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

Comment: What if the street is `Ahnewinkelstr. Hansstr. 3`?

Comment: The example doesn't have that format however 2 dots will be a problem

Comment: Will an address always have a number? I guess probaby not?

Comment: @FrankerZ `Ahnewinkelstr. Hansstr. 3` could be possible. So the  `Ahnewinkelstr. Hansstr.` should be the result. Once a numerical value appears, anything after it (including itself) should be omitted.

Comment: @Chiggiddi My updated answer should have solved that

Comment: @Antony your answer presupposes that a streetname always will have a .dot as a separater between street name and street number. But very often this is not the case. Many times there could be street names like these: ´Albert-Schmidt-Weg 1´ and ´Albert-Schmidt-Weg 3´, which won't get filtered by your method.

Comment: @Chiggiddi In the future, it would help if you include some of these "false positives", so that when creating the query we could know right away if it works or not.